# Error initialising struct with initialiser list with explicit constructor C++

Tags: c++, struct, initializer-list

I have a struct like this

```
struct Example {
    Example() = default;

    explicit Example(const cv::Point2f& landmark,
                      float Score = 0.0f,
                      float visibilityScore = 1.f,
                      float threshold = 0.5f)
        : point(landmark),
          score(Score),
          visibilityScore(visibilityScore),
          threshold(visibilityThreshold) {}

    cv::Point2f point{0, 0};
    float score{0.0f};
    float visibilityScore{1.f};
    float threshold{0.5f};
};
```

When I try to initialize individually like below, no compilation issue -

```
Example eg = {};
eg.point = cv::Point2f(0,0);
eg.visibilityScore = 2.f;
eg.score = 3.f;
eg.threshold = 0.5f;
```

When I try bracket initializer list like below, I get build error -

```
Example eg = {
.point = cv::Point2f(0, 0),
.score = 3.f,
.visibilityScore = 2.f,
.threshold = 0.5f};
```

Error -

```
no matching constructor for initialization of Example
note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'void' to 'const cv::Point2f' (aka 'const Point_<float>') for 1st argument
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 4 were provided
```

Question - Is it something to do with `explicit` or first constructor arg being `const&`?

Comment: Designated initializers are only available for aggregate types. Since you have a user-defined constructor your type is not an aggregate type

Comment: The code tries to use [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), but the class is not an aggregate (because of the constructor).